# How to make a model predict probability

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Am building a model using K nearest neighbours. The model predicts if someone has cancer or not. 1 for true, 0 for false. I need the model other than predicting presence of cancer or not giving a 0 or 1,how can i make the model also show the probability of the prediction being 1?

Edit:Am doing a project and it specifies i use the K nearest Neighbour classifier

Answer (score 2):

```py
probability = model.predict_proba(X)
```

This gives you an array of probabilities of being `0` and `1`.
If you need to check the probability of being `1` try

```py
probability_class_1 = model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a regressor instead of a classifier, meaning that a regression model can give you a probability of someone having a concern or not and the probability between the two values of 0 and 1, 0~1 (0~100%).

Comment: Actually you can use predict_proba with classification.